# Are all commutative, associative binary operations isomorphic to addition?

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, binary-operations

Addition and multiplication are the two classic commutative, associative binary operations on the reals. They satisfy a striking property: they are equivalent up to unary operations. By taking a logarithm of the arguments to addition and exponentiating the result, we get multiplication:

$xy = \exp(\log x + \log y)$

In fact, we can create a new commutative, associative operation from every invertible unary function $f$ in the same way:

$(x,y) \mapsto f^{-1} (f(x) + f(y))$

I actually haven't been able to come up with a commutative, associative operation that *doesn't* follow this form. Are all commutative, associative operations on the reals isomorphic to addition in a similar way?

---

*EDIT* - The answers and comments below give several good counterexamples to the problem as stated. Requiring $f$ to be invertible is too strong a condition. What if we allow this slightly more general functional form

$(x,y) \mapsto g (f(x) + f(y))$

where $f$ maps reals to some field and $g$ maps that field to the reals? This seems to capture the counterexamples. For example:

$(x, y) \mapsto 0$ matches with arbitrary $f$ and $g(z) = 0$

$(x, y) \mapsto x + y - \lfloor{x+y}\rfloor$ matches with $f(x) = x$ and $g(z) = z - \lfloor{z}\rfloor$

I think $(x, y) \mapsto max(x,y)$ matches with $f(x) = (x + a)^n$ and $g(z) = z^{1/n} - a$, where $a, n$ are constants we take to infinity. That choice is inspired by the relationship between the max function and the infinity norm. I get that including limits in $f$ and $g$ is pretty suspect, but even with that hack, it's interesting to me that it's possible.

Modifying the question slightly, can every commutative, associative binary operation be cast in the form $(x,y) \mapsto g (f(x) + f(y))$?

Comment: I think you have a counterexample hiding right in front of you: what exactly happens with negative numbers or zero under your claimed isomorphism between addition and multiplication?

Comment: max is commutative and associative, but not solvable.

Comment: what is the domain of $f$ meant to be? in your example, the domain of $f$ is only $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, not all of $\mathbb{R}$. anyway, denoting your binary operation by $\bullet$, you want an injective function $f$ on some domain such that $f(x\bullet y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for any $x,y$. what about the operation $\bullet:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $x\bullet y=0$? there is no injective function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying what you want here, since we would need $f(0)=f(x)+f(y)$ for any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. in particular, $f(x)=0$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ (why?)

Comment: In the power set $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{N})$ we have the binary commutative, associative operation $\Delta$
$$S \Delta R=(S\setminus R)\cup (R\setminus S).$$ That is, the symmetric difference of the subsets. This operation turns  $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{N})$ into a group. Furthermore, it has the property $S\Delta S=\emptyset$ for all $S$.
We have a bijection between $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{N})$ and $\Bbb{R}$.Similar transportation of structure gives you a binary commutative group operation on $\Bbb{R}$ with the extra property that $x\Delta x=0$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$. Therefore it cannot come from addition.

Comment: Addition modulo one, that is, $a*b=\{\,a+b\,\}$, the fractional part of $a+b$.

Comment: @MiloBrandt good point! If you allow for complex numbers and include a point at $-\infty$, I think the isomorphism actually does hold, but that admittedly requires the range of $f$ to be more than just the reals

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom you're right, requiring $f$ to be injective is too strong a condition. I've added an edit

Comment: @mrfish: your modified question is much more general than you intended, I think; see my edited answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can consider an operation that does not give the structure of a group. For instance
$$x\circ y\  \colon = \max(x,y)$$
Here we have $x \circ x = x$.  In fact we have a [lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)).

But even if the operation would give a commutative group, it may not be isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ with addition.  For instance $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is one such group of the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$.

You can check that an abelian group with the same cardinatlity as $\mathbb{R}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ with addition if an only if it is a uniquely-divisible group: for every $x$ and $n\ge 1$ integer, there exist a unique $y$ such that $ny = x$. Since then it is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$. However, a concrete isomorphism may not be available without some axiom of choice things. For instance, $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ with addition.

Answer (score 8):

**Edit:** The new version of your question is, I think, much more general than you intended; the answer is yes, due to the following cheap trick, but it doesn't really have anything to do with addition anymore.

Let $m : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be any commutative operation (we will not need associativity, and operations of the form $g(f(x) + f(y))$ will not be associative in general). We want to find $g, f$ such that $m(x, y) = g(f(x) + f(y))$. You say that $f$ can take values in "some field." We'll take this field to be the [function field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_function_field) $K = \mathbb{Q}(f_x, x \in \mathbb{R})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ on uncountably many variables, one for every real number, and $f : \mathbb{R} \to K$ will be the function $f(x) = f_x$. This guarantees that $f(x) + f(y) = f(z) + f(w)$ iff either $x = z$ and $y = w$ or $x = w$ and $y = z$; in other words, the value of $f(x) + f(y)$ uniquely determines the unordered pair $\{ x, y \}$.

Now we can take $g : K \to \mathbb{R}$ to be any function such that $g(f_x + f_y) = m(x, y)$; since $f_x + f_y$ uniquely determines $\{ x, y \}$ and $m$ is commutative this is well-defined. Of course we have not used any features of $\mathbb{R}$ in this argument, which can be replaced by an arbitrary set.

---

(This responds to the original question only.)

Your statement about addition and multiplication is not quite right; you only get an isomorphism between $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ and $(\mathbb{R}_{+}, \times)$ (where the subscript denotes taking positive reals). However, it is true that addition and multiplication are [locally isomorphic](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/08/17/notes-on-local-groups/) in a suitable sense.

> Are all commutative, associative operations on the reals isomorphic to addition in a similar way?

As stated, since you haven't asked for compatibility with any other structure on the reals, you are just asking for commutative [monoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid_(category_theory)) with the same cardinality as the reals. There is an enormous diversity of such things, even if we restrict further to [abelian groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group) (which means requiring inverses); as a random example, any countable product $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$ of at-most-countable but nontrivial abelian groups has the same cardinality as the reals, for example $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z}$, but such a group is isomorphic to the reals as an abstract group iff each $A_i$ is an at-most-countable-dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space.

However, we can get a positive result by requiring [continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function).

> **Proposition:** Every continuous abelian group structure on $\mathbb{R}$ (with its usual topology) is continuously isomorphic to addition.

This came up recently on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380434/map-of-endomorphism-operad/380497#380497). It follows from [Gleason-Montgomery-Zippin's solution to Hilbert's fifth problem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hilbert%27s+fifth+problem), which is almost certainly overkill; probably it follows from an easier and known structure theorem for [locally compact (Hausdorff) abelian groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_abelian_group) but I couldn't quite finish the argument. Maybe it can also be done "by hand."

(**Edit:** This is overkill, as expected. There is a totally elementary argument that a topological group (not necessarily abelian!) homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ must be isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R}, +)$; see [this math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/700565/group-structure-on-bbb-r/).)

If you further require smoothness then the proof is easier and can probably be done "by hand" more easily; abstractly, $\mathbb{R}$ is the unique $1$-dimensional [Lie algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra) and hence the unique $1$-dimensional simply connected [Lie group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group), so:

> **Corollary:** Any smooth abelian group structure on $\mathbb{R}$ is smoothly isomorphic to addition.

A related result you may be interested in is the classification of $1$-dimensional [formal group laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_group_law); over a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra, and in particular over $\mathbb{R}$, they are all isomorphic to the additive formal group law.

A question I don't know the answer to is whether it suffices to require [measurability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_function); that is, I don't know whether a measurable abelian group structure on $\mathbb{R}$ (with the [Borel $\sigma$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set), say) is measurably isomorphic to addition.

Comment: It can be shown "by hand" that every continuous group law $*$ on $\mathbf R$ (for its usual topology) is essentially addition: $x*y = f^{-1}(f(x) + f(y))$ for some homeomorphism $f \colon \mathbf R \to \mathbf R$.  The details are a bit tedious; one useful result is "Hion's lemma".  Concerning your question about measurability of a group law, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/120738/is-a-measurable-homomorphism-on-a-lie-group-smooth.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! Would you mind explaining the notation =ℚ(,∈ℝ) ?

Comment: @mrfish: it's a function field (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_function_field) of rational functions in uncountably many variables, one for each real number. This might be slightly overkill; I just need to be working somewhere big enough that $f(x) + f(y)$ uniquely determines $\{ x, y \}$. I might be able to get away with something like the field of meromorphic functions instead but then it'd be slightly less obvious that $g$ exists.

Answer (score 0):

"Isomorphic" refers to entire mathematical structure, not to an operation in that system. One could ask whether, given any set $S$ and an operation $*$, whether $(S,\star)$ is isomorphic to  $(\mathbb R, +)$, but the answer would be a rather trivial; for instance, $(\mathbb C,+)$ is not isomorphic to $(\mathbb R, +)$. If you want to restrict it to $(\mathbb R, \star)$ being isomorphic to  $(\mathbb R, +)$,  that doesn't really change anything essential; $\mathbb C$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb R$, so there exists bijections between them. Take any such bijection $\phi: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb C$, and we can define $a\star b$ for real numbers $a, b$ as $a\star b = \phi^{-1}(\phi(a)+ \phi(b))$ , and $(\mathbb R, \star)$ will not be isomorphic to $(\mathbb R, +)$.