# show that every continuous group law $∗$ on an open interval I has the form $x∗y = f(f^{-1} (x)+f^{ −1} (y))$ for some homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, abelian-groups

I was reading this https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/relativity.pdf PDF on RELATIVISTIC ADDITION AND GROUP THEORY and on remark 2.4 he says :

[image]

I'm trying to prove that remark buy I have no idea how to start